# (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

**I am trying to download a file from S3, I have already check, the file path is correct, the bucket do exist and my lambda function have fullAdmin Access to S3**

```
def download_file():
    s3_bucket_name = os.getenv("BUCKET_NAME")
    file_key=os.getenv("FILE_NAME")
    try:
        s3_client.download_file(s3_bucket_name, file_key, 'user-data')
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

**When my code is ran I get the following errors.**

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found",
  "errorType": "ClientError",
  "requestId": "e2145aa0-8ab6-4448-a410-d05fa8b3795f",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 106, in lambda_handler\n    user_list = read_agent_list(h_group)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 100, in read_agent_list\n    return map_agents_to_hgroup(userList,h_group)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 24, in map_agents_to_hgroup\n    download_file()#download the file to update\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 82, in download_file\n    raise e\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 80, in download_file\n    s3_client.download_file(s3_bucket_name, file_key, 'user-data')\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/boto3/s3/inject.py\", line 171, in download_file\n    return transfer.download_file(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/boto3/s3/transfer.py\", line 307, in download_file\n    future.result()\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/s3transfer/futures.py\", line 106, in result\n    return self._coordinator.result()\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/s3transfer/futures.py\", line 265, in result\n    raise self._exception\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/s3transfer/tasks.py\", line 255, in _main\n    self._submit(transfer_future=transfer_future, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/s3transfer/download.py\", line 340, in _submit\n    response = client.head_object(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 386, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 705, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to download an S3 object named "user-data", or one named after the contents of the value of the FILE_NAME environment variable ?

Comment: @AnonCoward - FILE_NAME is the environment variable which value is "user-data"

Comment: So the object is named "user-data" in S3?  Have you verified this with some other means?

Comment: correct, the object name is "user-data", I have verified this.